# Notice: MU gets more views per day in private beta than the other SE 2.0 sites get in public beta!

Tags: discussion

[Check it out](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics)!

6500 views per day.  That's pretty good!

Comment: Yeah, but 6000 of those are people looking for book recommendations ;)